# When viewDidLoad set textField editable / enable keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have an app with a `UITextField`. When the containing view appears, I want a keyboard to slide up and begin editing this text field. Not sure how I would go about doing this?

I've tried:

```
func viewDidLoad {
textField.editing == true
textField.selected == true
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear` add a call to `becomeFirstResponder`, something like this:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

or in Swift:

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: I used objective-c when I first post too. He's using Swift.